# How to remove highlight on Delete key

Tags: jquery, html

I have a search highlight that I have created, but for some reason its not removing the search highlight when the backspace or delete key is hit. I was able to get the event to work when "Enter" key is hit but for some reason its not working when the delete or backspace key is hit. Below is my code:

```
<script>
$input.keypress("input", function(e) {
if (e.keyCode === 13) {  
var searchVal = this.value;
$content.unmark({
  done: function(totalMatches) {
    $content.mark(searchVal, {
      separateWordSearch: false,
      acrossElements: true,
      done: function(totalMatches) {
        $results = $content.find("mark");
        currentIndex = 0;
        jumpTo();

            //tag.addClass('active');
        totalCount=totalMatches;
            if (totalMatches) {

          variableCounter=1;
          $(".kwt-count").html(variableCounter+ " of " +totalMatches+" Matches");
            }
        else
        {
           $(".kwt-count").html(" Matches");
        }

      }
    });
  }
});
}
}); 

  /**
   * Clears the search
   */
  $clearBtn.keypress("click", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46) {
    $content.unmark();
    $input.val("").focus();
    }
  });
</script>
```

I have created a codepen of the code here: https://codepen.io/dude12go8/pen/PoYbdXd

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only runs when you hit the enter key.

The keycode's for backspace and delete are `46` and `8`. Update your conditional to also account for these:

```
if (e.keyCode === 13 || e.keyCode === 46 || e.keyCode === 8)
```

Comment: I tried implementing that by going back to the codepen and it still only works for when I hit the enter key, but not the delete key to remove the highlight.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I just realized your using `keypress` instead of `keydown`. Try update `keypress` to `keydown`.

Comment: that worked! One last question. When I hit the delete key and remove the verbiage from the input field, I have to hit the delete key one more time to unhighlight everything. Why would it do that?

Comment: Sorry for making you switch again. We are going to want to update AFTER press, so we are going to now change `keydown` to `keyup` so it takes value after release.

Comment: lol. No worries. I ended up getting to work. Thanks for the help!